# agrupar cada periodo por mes

Tags: sql, query, datetime, group-by, case

Estou fazendo essa consulta, porem não estou conseguindo agrupar cada período por mês, do ano anterior.

Para cada mês do ano anterior ao ano corrente, retornar a quantidade de carros estacionados por período (de `00:00` a `07:59`, `08:00` a `15:59` e `16:00` a `23:59`).

Consulta:

```sql
select 
  ent_datahora_entrada as mes, veiculos as periodo  , count(*) 
from (
      select  
      
       to_char(ent_datahora_entrada, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi') ent_datahora_entrada 
        
      , case when to_char(ent_datahora_entrada, 'hh24:mi')>='00:00'
              and to_char(ent_datahora_entrada, 'hh24:mi')<='07:59' then '0 as 8'
             when to_char(ent_datahora_entrada, 'hh24:mi')>='08:00'
              and to_char(ent_datahora_entrada, 'hh24:mi')<='15:59' then '8 as 16'
             when to_char(ent_datahora_entrada, 'hh24:mi')>='16:00'
              and to_char(ent_datahora_entrada, 'hh24:mi')<='23:59' then '16 as 0'
             
        end veiculos
      from entradas_saidas
     ) 
group by ent_datahora_entrada, veiculos ;
```

Está saindo assim:

```
12/01/0020 09:26  |8 as 16 |1
14/01/0020 11:26  |8 as 16 |1
19/01/0020 16:26  |16 as 0 |1
28/01/0020 01:26  |0 as 8  |1
17/02/0020 21:26  |16 as 0 |1
01/03/0020 10:26  |8 as 16 |1
```

O que preciso é que agrupe todas as datas do mês. Exemplo : `01/01/19` até `01/02/19` para todos os meses.

```
 8 as 16   |  5
16 as 00   | 10
00 as 8    | 7
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tem de transformar o campo de data `ent_datahora_entrada` de forma a que este tenha o formato pretendido.

Desta forma:

```
select 
  ent_datahora_entrada as mes, veiculos as periodo  , count(*) 
from (
      select          
        to_char(ent_datahora_entrada, 'mm/yyyy') ent_datahora_entrada,          
        case when to_char(ent_datahora_entrada, 'hh24:mi')>='00:00'
              and to_char(ent_datahora_entrada, 'hh24:mi')<='07:59' then '0 as 8'
             when to_char(ent_datahora_entrada, 'hh24:mi')>='08:00'
              and to_char(ent_datahora_entrada, 'hh24:mi')<='15:59' then '8 as 16'
             when to_char(ent_datahora_entrada, 'hh24:mi')>='16:00'
              and to_char(ent_datahora_entrada, 'hh24:mi')<='23:59' then '16 as 0'                 
        end veiculos
      from entradas_saidas
) 
group by ent_datahora_entrada, veiculos;
```

Comment: Legal! no caso quero que retorne apenas os meses do ano de 2019. Como faço?

Comment: Na pesquisa mais interior coloque um filtro sobre os dados com um conjunto de condições depois da cláusula `WHERE`.

Comment: Muito obrigada pela ajuda! consegui resolver.